# Substring Occurrences

Tags: python, substring

I have a question here and I really don't know where to start on it short of

```
s1.find(s2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Variables s1 and s2 refer to strs. The expression s1.find(s2) returns the index of the first occurrence of s2 in s1. The expression s1.find(s2, 5) returns the index of the first occurrence of s2 in s1, starting at index 5 within s1. (See help(str.find) for more info)

Write an expression that produces the index of the second occurrence of s2 in s1. If s2 does not occur twice in s1, the expression should produce -1. Unlike str.count, you should allow overlapping occurrences of s2.

For example, if s1 is "banana" and s2 is "ana", your expression should return 3. If s1 is "apple" and s2 is "p", your expression should return 2.

Your answer must be a single expression that does not use square brackets (string indexing and slicing), and you can only call method str.find and use the arithmetic operators (+, -, etc.).

Comment: What could you set the second argument of `find` to make it give you the second occurrence of `s2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This prints 3.

```
s1 = 'banana'
s2 = 'ana'
second_index = s1.find(s2, s1.find(s2)+1)
print(second_index)
```

This prints -1.

```
s1 = 'bana'
s2 = 'ana'
second_index = s1.find(s2, s1.find(s2)+1)
print(second_index)
```

Thus the expression you are probably looking for is `s1.find(s2, s1.find(s2)+1)`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why the second s1.find(s2)+1 is located where it is? When I read this I see find s2 within is 1 for everything to the left of the comma, and I'm unsure how the right side functions in conjunction with the left.

Comment: @Zack In the first example, `s1.find(s2)` returns 1. If you just did `s1.find(s2, s1.find(s2))` it would return 1 again. But we want to start searching at index 2. I added 1 to the index returned by `s1.find(s2)` so that it would start searching for the substring *beyond* the first index that it found which was 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation for clues:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html