# how to skip over a character with .find in python

Tags: python, string

just wondering if there was a simple way of skipping over a letter in a string whilst using .find()
eg, im looking for a certain letter in a word, perhaps o in proportion.
proportion.find(o)
I've already found the position of the first o. how would i find the position of the second or third o without having to remove the first o from the word?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753105/substring-occurrences

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'helloworld'
selectedCharacter = 'o'
print [position for position, char in enumerate(string) if char == selectedCharacter]
```

this will give you a list of the indexes of the selected character (in this case the character 'o', will give you `[4, 6]`)